# Best way of connecting a signal from QGraphicsItem to its QGraphicView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a widget that inherhits from QGraphicsView like so:

```
class MyWidget : public QGraphicsView
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent);
  ...
  signal:
    mySignal();
}
```

This QGraphicsView has a scene and the scene has added (custom) items that inherit from QGraphicsObject so that signal/slots are implemented:

```
class CustomItem : public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomItem();

    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
    ...
signal:
    void itemSignal();
}
```

When the item is in focus I want to connect to MyWidget's mySignal, like so:

```
void CustomItem::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(itemSignal()), ???,SIGNAL(mySignal()));
}
```

As you can see I've filled in the pointer to MyWidget with question marks simply because I'm not sure what the best way to get a pointer to it is. I've tried going through the documentation to see if the item inherits any method or similar to get its QGraphicsView, but I haven't been able to find anything. Is passing MyWidget's this pointer to the CustomItem's constructor and save it a good approach?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are complicating things. You probably create these `CustomItem`s in a class that holds the instance of `MyWidget`. Connect the `CustomItem::itemSignal` to `MyWidget::mySignal` over there. Also connecting same signal multiple times means it will be triggered multiple times.

Comment: Which Qt-version is in use. Could you already use the function-pointer--based connect semantic? Your version is based on the deprecated string-base signal-slot-concept and should not be used any more.

Comment: Putting the technical aspects aside, what is the goal here? When a QGraphicsObject based instance gains focus, what are you planning to do in the QGraphicsView?

Comment: Thank you all for replying. To answer @TheDarkKnight first, the goal is to send certain properties of the item to the widget which will then propagate the signal further to an interface class used by a third party application that I have no control over. This third party app is supposed to display the focused item's properties and since it has to be sent to the same slot in the interface class I thought connecting and disconnecting the item would be the best approach.

Comment: @thuga thanks for your reply. I should have emphasized that I planned to disconnect when the item is out of focus. You're right that I create them where I have access to MyWidget pointer, but for the reasons I explained in the answer to TheDarkKnight I want to do the connect when the item is in focus.

Comment: IMO, from a design point of view it seems strange to link the focussed object to the View. Considering the objects belong to the scene and the view is simply a window into the scene, whilst it's a little more complex, I'd opt for sending the signal to the scene and then from the scene to forward the signal for attached views.

Comment: Why disconnect the signal? Why don't you just emit the signal if the item has focus?

Comment: @thuga Yup, I over complicated things and did it your way :) Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

One hint: You need to connect the signal itemSignal() with a corresponding **slot**:

```
MyWidget widget;
QObject::connect( this, &CustomItem::itemSignal, &widget, &MyWidget::itemSlot );
// or for older Qt-versions
QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL(itemSignal(), &widget, SLOT( itemSlot ) );
```

When you don't have the pointer to your widget you can search the object tree via QGraphicsView::items() and search for your widget.

Comment: Thank you for replying :) Not using slot was intentional because my widget class must propogate the signal further to an interface class because my widget will be used in a third party application. I'll try to search the object tree!